# How can I see examples of CVs on careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs, search

I am a student at university. For the summer, I must do an internship at a company, but before that I need to prepare a CV. I read some questions on programmers, and some users say "for CV examples, go and look at careers". However, I can only see five CVs -- how do I go about browsing many CVs on that site?

Answer (score 5):

`site:http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ -inurl:jobs`

Place that in your Google search and you are all set.

*These are profiles that are currently set to public by the user*

Answer (score 2):

You can visit the [FAQ page on careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq), drop down the employer questions and click the blue link titled [See a sample profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/sample-profile).